# Using an Arduino (If Needed) to Charge 18650 Battery

Tags: arduino, batteries, battery-charging, safety

I am looking for a way to charge 18650 battery with an Arduino (If needed) as simple as possible.

I have seen tutorials where you have to buy 10 diffident parts. I just want the simple (But wont light it on fire Haha) method for a poor kid with 30 battery's extracted from laptop battery's to charge them.

Also side question, what is a safe voltage to determine if a battery is bad EX: one of my battery's are at 2.1V and one is 3.4V

Comment: Keep a fire extinguisher handy.  With some luck, you may be able to put out secondary fires with it.

Comment: lol Haha will do

Comment: Is it necessary to use an Arduino for your application? You do get Battery charging modules which do not require an Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.1V is dangerously low.
A variable power supply will be helpful.
Connect a voltage of 3.5 to 4 volts via a 100 Ohm resistor to the cell. 
(V- or ground to cell -ve.)
(V+ via resistor to V+.)
Vcharge will be about (Vsupply-Vcell)/Rseries ~~= (4-2)/100 = 20 mA.
At this rate it would take 50 hours to charge a small 1000 mAh cell.
Observe battery voltage.
If it rises to say 3V then the battery can then be charged normally.
If Vcell remains under say 2.8V indefinitely it is beyond reasonable salvation.

V_ABSOLUTE_max_cell = 4.2V.

**___________________________________________**

18650 cells in older laptops usually have capacities of 2000 mAh or more.
Safe usual charging rate is C/1 = 2000 mA **BUT** some cells have C/2 = 1000 mA max limit.  Charging at an amp or less if a good start.

You can make a very simple charger if desired. Using a charging IC may be easier and usually is less prone to vent-with-flame accidents.

Simple:
- Charge at 1A max from 4.2V source limit current with supply current limit or other means.
- Constantly monitor battery voltage at battery terminals.
- If Vcell = 4.2V charging is complete.
Battery will be at typically 70% - 80% of max capacity.

The above process can be automated with an Arduino or other embedded processor.
Charge termination voltage can be measured with an Arduino analog ADC input. Charge voltage can be controlled with a MOSFET or bipolar 'switch'

If desired current can be limited by PWM of a pass transistor and filtering. If the PWM dies the battery may too.

Current may be measured with a low value resistor in the battery negative lead and an Arduino ADC. Battery voltage at +ve terminal will be Vcell + Vcurrent_sense.

If desired the more complex CC/CV charging mode may be used.
Charging at C/1 or C/2 occurs until Vcell = 4/2V CC charging happens. If Vcell is limited to 4.2V max then the CV mode will be entered automatically when Vcell = 4.2V.  Then allow ICell to drop until it reaches say Imax/4.
An Arduino can easily implement this algorithm.

More soon ...........

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need a Li-Ion charging controller like the MCP73831. There are also lots of ready-made solutions available, e.g. https://www.adafruit.com/products/1304

Comment: im looking to "build" the required device if possible. I can get parts easier than components.